# Add class and remove others

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, addclass, removeclass

So i have a simple dropdown menu and i'm facing a challenge because I've built a simple colorpicker that removes a class and add another,all this without removing the essential classes of the dropdown.
  I've tried with .filter() and .not() but nothing seems to work.
  Here is the jQuery part :

```
$('ul.colopicker li').click(function(){
var $text = $(this).text();
  $('ul#navmenu li, ul.sub1 li, ul.sub2 li').removeClass($text);
  $('ul#navmenu li, ul.sub1 li, ul.sub2 li').addClass($text);
});
```

And here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/gFSac/) .

```
My question is: Can anyone modify the jQuery so that when i click the colors to add class but not remove the default one
```

Comment: so what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell what you want to acheive, but you may have better luck with something like:

```
$('ul.colopicker li').click(function(){
var $text = $(this).text();
    $('.'+$text).removeClass('red blue');
    $('ul#navmenu li, ul.sub1 li, ul.sub2 li').addClass($text);
});
```

Comment: I want to give the dropdown the class of red or blue,without removing the default class of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background of all `li`s maybe its better to switch the class only on the `ul`:

CSS:

```
.red li {background-color:red !important;}
.blue li {background-color:blue !important;}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('ul.colopicker li').click(function(){
    var $text = $(this).text();  
    $('ul#navmenu').removeClass().addClass($text);
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gFSac/1/

Comment: I want to give the dropdown the class of red or blue,without removing the default class of the dropdown

Comment: From your fiddle I can not see what the default class is that you want to keep.